# How should the dependency tree of a React Flux application correlate with Flux control flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

In reference to the example React.js Flux tutorial project [Part 1: Building web app using react.js, express.js, node.js and mongodb](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1067725/Part-Building-web-app-using-react-js-express-js), it would be helpful to understand why the dependency calls don't seem to always follow the same positive or negative correlation with the direction of the arrows in the Flux flow diagram as shown below (note the situations where calls are opposite to that of the arrows):

[image: Flux diagram Source]
Flux diagram Source: https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html

Modules in the "View" category include:

```
main.jsx (View calls Store in OPPOSITE direction of arrow as well as other view components)
components/SchoolsList.jsx (View calls other View components)
components/SchoolsInfo.jsx (View calls Action in direction of arrow)
components/AddSchool.jsx (View calls Action in direction of arrow)
```

Modules in the "Action" category include:

```
dispatcher.js (Action calls Dispatcher in direction of arrow)
```

Modules in the "Dispatcher" category include:

```
dispatcher.js (Does not call other Flux blocks. Only call is to guid lib)
```

Modules in the "Store" category include:

```
schoolStore.js (Store calls Dispatcher in the OPPOSITE direction of arrow)
```

To be clear, the question is how do the dependency calls map to the arrows? In particular it would be helpful to see an explanation that reconciles the inconsistent correlation of arrow direction to dependency calls.

Comment: The arrows represent flow of data, not dependency directions. The store is not dispatching anything, just registering itself to the dispatcher so it can react to actions. I highly recommend looking at redux. it's simple, elegant flux (without the dispatcher part) http://redux.js.org/

Comment: @azium thanks for the quick feedback. Any quick thoughts on how redux overhead and learning curve compares to flux? Amount of refactoring to migrate an application from flux to redux?

Comment: Redux learning curve is far more lenient than the original flux pattern that FB put out there (they use Redux now). Fewer things to know about, less code to write, easier mental model. Migrations can be a pain, kinda depends on how far in your are I guess. I would do the redux tutorial and feel out the migration pain yourself. There might not be any!